# Minimizing the distance between curves stacked on each other in R plot

Tags: r, function, plot, polygon

I have an `R` function that plots some curves stacked on top of each other (*see picture below the code*).

I was wondering, however, how I could *adjust the distance between the curves* (s*ee blue arrows*) so that the curves don't look so flat?

Also, is it possible to use `polygon` instead of `lines` to plot these curves?

```
stacked = function(a, b, lo, hi, d, Bi = 55, n = 1e2){

h = list()

for(i in 1:length(d)){
         p = function(x) get(d[i])(x, a, b)
     prior = function(x) p(x)/integrate(p, lo, hi)[[1]]
likelihood = function(x) dbinom(Bi, n, x)
 posterior = function(x) prior(x)*likelihood(x)
      h[i] = list(curve(posterior, ty = "n", ann = FALSE, yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n", add = i!= 1, bty = "n", n = 1e3))
}
plot(matrix(c(rep(c(.4, .8), each = length(d))), length(d), 2), rep(1:length(d), 2), ty = "n", xlim = 0:1, ann = FALSE, xaxt = "n", ylim = c(1, length(d)+.4))

for(i in 1:length(d)){
lines(h[[i]]$x, h[[i]]$y+i, ty = "l", xpd = NA, col = i)
  }
}
# Example of use:
stacked(lo = 0, hi = 1, a = 2, b = 3, d = c("dgamma", "dnorm", "dcauchy", "dbeta", "dlogis", "dweibull"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just scale the y-values before drawing the lines.  I have added a `scale` parameter to your function.  Try scale =2 or 3

```
stacked = function(a, b, lo, hi, d, Bi = 55, n = 1e2, scale=1){

    h = list()
    for(i in 1:length(d)) {
             p = function(x) get(d[i])(x, a, b)
         prior = function(x) p(x)/integrate(p, lo, hi)[[1]]
    likelihood = function(x) dbinom(Bi, n, x)
     posterior = function(x) prior(x)*likelihood(x)
          h[i] = list(curve(posterior, ty = "n", ann = FALSE, yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n", add = i!= 1, bty = "n", n = 1e3))
    }
    plot(matrix(c(rep(c(.4, .8), each = length(d))), length(d), 2), rep(1:length(d), 2), ty = "n", xlim = 0:1, ann = FALSE, xaxt = "n", ylim = c(1, length(d)+.4))

    for(i in 1:length(d)){
        lines(h[[i]]$x, scale*h[[i]]$y+i, ty = "l", xpd = NA, col = i)
      }
}

stacked(lo = 0, hi = 1, a = 2, b = 3, scale=2,
    d = c("dgamma", "dnorm", "dcauchy", "dbeta", "dlogis", "dweibull"))
```

If you wish to fill in the area under the curves,  you can use `polygon`. Change the lines:

```
for(i in 1:length(d)){
        lines(h[[i]]$x, scale*h[[i]]$y+i, ty = "l", xpd = NA, col = i)
      }
```

TO

```
for(i in 1:length(d)){
    polygon(x=h[[i]]$x, y=scale*h[[i]]$y+i, col = i)
  }
```